# How can we read a config file stored at a location relative to the Mirth Connect Installation directory?

Tags: mirth, hl7-v3

How can we read a config file stored at a location relative to the Mirth Connect Installation directory?

For example if Mirth is installed in /opt/Mirth-Connect directory and I want to read a file from /opt/Mirth-Connect/conf directory without specifying the fully qualified path name.

We are using multiple instances of Mirth for different environments which are installed on the same machine, So I can't hard code full path in channel configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can read *a config file stored at a location relative to the Mirth Connect Installation directory* basically in the same way as you would read any other file, i.e.:

```
var folder = new java.io.File("./conf");
var listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (var i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        // Do what you need with the file - listOfFiles[i].getName());
     } 
}
```

The first line gives you a path relative to the mcserver.exe (in Windows env) installation. 
Accordingly, folder = File(".") is a Mirth root folder.